# ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'example@example.com'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to create a superuser but it's giving the above error.

And  I can't exactly find at which line I'm getting the error.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from .models import *
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from .form import *
from django.db import IntegrityError
# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    if not myUser.is_authenticated:
        message = "signed in as {Customer.first_name}"
    else :
        message = "please sign in"
    return render(request, "auctions/index.html",{
        "listings": Listings.objects.all(),
        "message":message

    })

def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = loginForm()
        email = request.POST["email"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        user = authenticate(request,username=email,password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request,email,password)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
        else:
            return render(request, "auctions/login.html",{
                "form": form ,
                "message": "username/password not valid"
            })
    return render(request, "auctions/login.html",{
        "form": loginForm()
    })

def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return render(request, "auctions/login.html")

def register(request):
    if request.POST == "POST":
        form = registerForm()
        email = request.POST["email"]

        # check passwords are same
        password = request.POST["password"]
        confirmation = request.POST["confirmation"]

        if password != confirmation:
            return render (request, "auctions/register.html",{
                "form": form,
                "message": "Passwords does not match"
            })
        
        # Attempt to create new user
        try:
            user = myUser.objects.create_user(email,password)
            user.save()
        except IntegrityError:
            return render(request, "auctions/register.html", {
                "form":form,
                "message": "Username is already taken"
            })

        login(request,user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))

    return render(request, "auctions/register.html", {
        "form": registerForm()
    })
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser,BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

# Create your models here.
class myUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    custom user model manager where email is unique indentifiers for authenticaton
    instead of usernames.
    """

    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('The Email must be set'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):

        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
        """

        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff',True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser',True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active',True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff= True'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(email,password, **extra_fields)

class myUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = myUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.email}'

class Listings(models.Model):
    listing_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    date_listed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    item_image = models.ImageField()
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200, default="Description Not Available")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.listing_name}'
```

I even tried deleting files inside migrations and remigrating them but it still shows the same error.

Thanks and I really appreciate your efforts in helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `django.contrib.auth.login` is defined as `def login(request, user, backend=None)`. You pass it the wrong arguments (`login(request,email,password)`).

Your view should be:

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = loginForm()
        email = request.POST["email"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        user = authenticate(request,username=email,password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user) # ← here
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
        else:
            return render(request, "auctions/login.html",{
                "form": form ,
                "message": "username/password not valid"
            })
    return render(request, "auctions/login.html",{
        "form": loginForm()
    })
```

Also in your `create_user` method you write `self.model(email, **extra_fields)` but that's incorrect. Your method should be:

```
def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    """
    Create and save a User with the given email and password.
    """
    if not email:
        raise ValueError(_('The Email must be set'))
    email = self.normalize_email(email)
    user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()
    return user
```

Comment: thanks, I was so confused I didn't notice that